# BASH: How to copy a file without overwriting older files

Tags: bash, unix, rsync, cp

I'd like to know how to copy a file without overwriting an older file, I do not have -n switch available.

Both the cp -u and rsync will overwrite older files as far as I'm aware and I do not want this behaviour, I'd like to always keep the older files.

Thanks

Comment: if it's an option, you can write a little script to do it.  That's my preferred method of doing things.  That way I can have 100% customization with regards to behavior

Comment: Do you have the -b option available to you?

Comment: @RussellUhl, beware the risk of TOCTOU when writing a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "`--interactive`" option (present in my `cp` from `GNU coreutils 6.12`) to prompt you before overwriting and fill it with a default:

```
echo 'n' | cp --interactive ~/somefile.txt ~/somefile_already_exists.txt
```

Comment: The question states "a file", but you're right: `yes n` is a more general solution.

Comment: Note that even if you are using `cp -ir a/* b/` (multiple questions) `echo 'n' |` is ok. (have tested) I would have expected echo 'n' would suppress the first question only... will have to investigate this

Comment: `true | ..` or `< /dev/null` is enough, since `cp` safely defaults to "no"

Answer (score 1):

Copy the file to a newly created temporary file in the same directory (see `mktemp` or `tempfile` under Linux). Then use `ln` to attempt to give the copy the name you want. `ln` will fail if the name exists; you could try to use a different name, or just issue an error message, or whatever. Finally, remove the temporary name.

Comment: Sorry, I wish to avoid copying the file (it is large), thanks.

Comment: @JimMoyle: then test to see if the file exists before doing the above. Once in a while, you'll end up with a pointless copy but the atomic copy outlined above will at least prevent data races.

Answer (score -3):

This is a non-interactive approach.  It checks if the file exists (after an initial appending of a random number).  If it does then it looks for another random number.  This can be reworked in different ways.  Arguments can be added, and so forth.

```
   copyfile() {
      n=$RANDOM
      while [ -f $1__$n ]      
       do
       n=$RANDOM
       done
       cp $1 $1__$n
    }
```

usage:

```
copyfile file_to_copy
```

your file will be named somthing like:

Originalfile.txt_20625

The appended number most likely prevents any chance of overwriting.  If this is not enough then one could add anything they wish to the end of the file, like a time stamp.  If you are still worried about overwriting after these measures then you probably should be backing up your files on a regular basis.

Comment: Remove characters? Jim isn't looking to remove, but to copy.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  This does copy a file.  This site is ridiculous.

Comment: @BobBlogge, have you read the question carefully?  If `file_copy` existed already, using your example it would be overwritten.

Comment: @BobBlogge I've not downvoted it but the solution looks a little bit weird. If you want to copy a file use `cp` .. But the question was how to copy files without overwriting the destination if exists

Comment: Your edit is still incorrect.  What if `file_to_copy_copy` already exists?

Comment: What if `file_to_copy__$n` is created after the check in your `while` loop but before the `tr`?  Why use the `tr` over plain 'ol `cp`, or `cat`?

Comment: @BrianCain  Changed it to cp.